# Tools to map threads to their memory usage?

Tags: java

Having some performance issues in a Weblogic 11g production system.

As part of the debugging effort, I’m interested in finding a way to map threads to their memory usage, then seeing the stack to determine what part of the application is consuming so much.

Anyone know of a tool or method to do what I want to do?

I'm not interested in JProbe memory profiling as it requires too much overhead (taking snapshots of everything). Also, I've read about Heapwalker in NetBeans that seems promising.

Comment: I don't think "per-thread memory usage" is even a meaningful term in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse has a memory analyzer (or heap walker, if you will) called mat - http://eclipse.org/mat/.

I've used it in the past and it was pretty helpful. I don't remember off-hand all the features, but I do remember being able to identify "heavy" threads, querying for largest objects, and such.

The home page links to several tutorials and a blog that are useful as well.

Comment: thanks. this is good information and useful to me. but i need to be able to do this in a system currently deployed in production so i am looking for tools that can be deployed/used in that context.

Comment: you can get a heap dump of a running java process (in more than one way, e.g. jmap) and then copy the heap dump over to where eclipse+mat are located. That's how I did it.